# All these divs wont go away

Tags: jquery, function, fadeout

I'm trying to run a script that will fade out all the divs selected randomly.

It always seems to leave a couple sitting at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/1/

**JS**

```
    function hideCube() {
    $('#group').show('slow');
    $('.pxl').each(function(index, element) {
        var sleepTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
            var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
            $(element).fadeTo(d, 0);
        }, sleepTime);
    });
}

$(function() {

    $('.pxl').each(function(index, element) {
        var sleepTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
            var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            $(element).fadeTo(d, 0.99);
        }, sleepTime);
    });

    var h = setTimeout(hideCube, 3000);

});
```

Comment: What exactly is the first timeout for? the one not inside the hideCube function.
The problem seems to be that the two timeouts "overlap".

Comment: You have expressions like `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)` a number of times in your code - this violates DRY. Consider an utility function: `var randint = function ( ceiling ) { return Math.floor( Math.random() * ceiling ); };`. And then: `randint(5000)`, `randint(4000)`, and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler.

```
// return random integer, 0 <= n < ceiling
var randint = function ( ceiling ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ceiling );
};

$( '.pxl' ).delay( 5000 ).each(function () {
    $( this ).delay( randint(5000) ).fadeTo( randint(5000), 0 );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/31/

Comment: Without doubt, the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here, all DIVs disappear:

```
var randint = function ( ceiling ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ceiling );
};

setTimeout(function () {
    $( '.pxl' ).each(function ( i, elem ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $( elem ).fadeTo( randint(5000), 0 );
        }, randint(5000) );
    });
}, 4000 );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/25/

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
$(element).fadeTo(d, 0.99);
```

to:

```
$(element).fadeTo(d, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/12/

Answer (score 1):

just call your function: http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/8/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the second `$('pxl').each()` loop seems to fix your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/MQFFf/4/